How to get rid of the dimming on the previous/current page when im navigating to a page in react native
I'm using react native navigation and when i try to navigate to a page or go back, it "dims/lower opacity" the current page and generates the animation of left to write to show focus on the page im trying to focus on by default. I like the animation of swiping left to right but no the "dimming" part since it creates a crease from the header
creates an dim on the current page which shows the crease. while navigating when i have a header. how do i not make it dim while navigation in a stack in react navigation. navigation/goback
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 50}}>
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}> //header
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -25,
            width: '25%',
            backgroundColor: theme.primary,
            height: 7,
            borderRadius: 10,
            zIndex: 1,
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <AddNavigator.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
          contentStyle: {
           
          },
        }}>
        <AddNavigator.Screen
          name={APP_MODAL.a}
          component={Ascreen}
        />
        <AddNavigator.Screen
          name={APP_MODAL.b}
          component={BScreen}
        />
      </AddNavigator.Navigator>
    </View>

https://streamable.com/vsgz9w
^ example video for easier understanding. (i want to get rid of the crease while navigating)

You can use @react-navigation/stack and do something like this :
import {createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets} from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const TransitionScreenOptions = {
  ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
};

const StackScreen = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      gestureEnabled: true,
      gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
      TransitionScreenOptions,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={FirstScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={SecondScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);


I'm using native stack which doesnt have transitionSpec :(

I have updated it now check !

Ahh i guess theres no way to do it for native stack navigator?

i think you need to check your @react-navigation/stack version, if you are on latest version then visit documentation for clear vision : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transitionpresets
